# Добавить строку в таблицу для ввода данных

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть страница:

```js
function handler(e) {
  var divNode = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
//  
};
var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
var b2 = document.getElementById("b2");
b1.addEventListener("click", handler);
b2.addEventListener("click", handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="t1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>0001</td>
      <td>СОШ № 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="b1">+</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  <table id="t2" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>0286</td>
      <td>СОШ № 34</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="b2">+</button>
</div>
```

ВОПРОС

Как создать **один обработчик** (handler) для **двух кнопок** (+), который добавит строку в таблицу для ввода данных. *Изначально отображаемые данные (0001|СОШ № 2) должны оставаться неизменяемыми.*

ПОПЫТКИ

Я начал писать обработчик и как видите, для начала я определил родительский узел, чтобы узнать какой из button_ов сработал. Хоть убей, но не смог выполнить select своей таблицы.

Comment: достаточно найти все нужные вам узлы `var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')` а потом через цикл повесить обработчик и всё.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, обработчик повесили, а дальше - как в нем (обработчике) узнать `button` какой таблицы сработал?

Comment: у вас же структура должна быть получается жесткая. Каждая кнопка под каждой таблицей. Соответственно, previous sibling  (не помню как на js..... кажется получится `e.previousSibling`) - это нужная таблица

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с `jquery`, то можно так:

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  $(this).prev().find("tbody").append('<tr><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" /></td>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table id="t1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0001</td>
        <td>СОШ № 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  <table id="t2" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0286</td>
        <td>СОШ № 34</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button class="btn">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно всё упростить для понимания сути происходящего. Пусть немного криво. Зато будет понятно.
Напиши функцию handler(), но прими туда какой нибудь аргумент. Например нажимает верхний + пусть X=1; нажмёт другой будет X=2. В итоге у тебя один обработчик делает в одном случае так, а вдругом иначе)